# Returning a value from a recursive function

Tags: c++, recursion, tree

Another recursion problem, sorry just cant get my head round this. I'm trying to return a node pointer whose id matches the supplied id. I think I'm traversing the tree correctly. Any ideas where I'm going wrong here?

```
//h
Node* findNode(const QString &id, Node *node=NULL)

//cpp
Node* Tree::findNode(const QString &id, Node *node)
{
    if (node == NULL)
        node = root;

    for(int i = 0, end = node ? node->childCount() : -1; i < end ; i++)
    {
        QString nodeId = node->child(i)->id();

        if (nodeId == id)
        {
            return node;
        }
        else
        {
            return findNode(id, node->child(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for looking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you need something like:

```
 ...
 else
 {
     Node *temp = findNode(id, node->child(i));
     if (temp) return temp;
 }
```

As it is, it's returning before it reaches the end of your loop.

Also, you need to return `NULL` (or better yet, `nullptr`) at the end of your function:

```
// At the end
return NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks everyone. Mats, in the else clause the node id doesn't match the desired id so why do I need to return the node?

Comment: The `return temp;` is to replace the the `return findNode(...)` - it means that you found what you are looking for in a child-node. Obviously, if `temp` is NULL, you need to keep looking. In your original code, you always returned at this point, so you never looked at all the nodes a ta particular level - which is clearly wrong. But you don't want to keep looking if you found something, so return if you have.

Answer (score 4):

In the `else`, only return the value from the recursive call if something was found. Otherwise, you'll never get past `i=0`

Answer (score 1):

```
else return findNode(id, node->child(i));`
```

this will lead to the traversal of **the first subtree (child) only.**

I would rather write something like this in order to traverse **all** subtrees in order, until something is found. If nothing is found, return `nullptr`:

```
Node *find(Node *tree, string id)
{
    if (tree->id == id)
        return tree;

    Node *ptr = nullptr;
    for (int i = 0; i < tree->childCount; i++)
        if ((ptr = find(node->children[i], id)) != nullptr)
            return ptr;

    return nullptr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to do only a depth first search, and return the result of the leftmost leaf node.

In findNode(id, node->child(i)); you never check if this returns NULL.

Return only from there if the return value from the child is not NULL (you actually found something), otherwise, continue in the loop (right now, you only look at the first element).

Then, after the loop, if nothing has been found (no return yet), return NULL.